# ProgressDialog doesn't show after clicking HOME and returning to App

Tags: android, dialog, progressdialog

In my onCreate, the following code executes:

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);  
dialog.setCancelable(false);  
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);  
dialog.setMessage("Welcome! Initializing database... This will take just a minute");
dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
dialog.setMax(100);
dialog.setProgress(0);
dialog.show();
```

The dialog should only go away once an AsyncTask completes. If I click home and then return to the application the ProgressDialog should still be there, and in fact, that's what happens in the emulator. On my HTC Evo, however, the dialog does not show if I click home and return to the app.

I also have:

```
@Override 
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    try {
        dialog.show();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {}
}
```

Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

**Updated (most relevant code):**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = this;
    RecipeDbAdapter rdAdapter;
    int recipesInDb = 0;

    // Binds automatically to "@android:id/list"
    setContentView(R.layout.country_list);
    setListAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));

    handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Bundle b = msg.getData();
            String type = b.getString("type");
            String data = b.getString("data");

            // If message received to advance dialog (called during initial db load)
            try {
                if (type.equals("dialog")) {
                    dialog.incrementProgressBy(Integer.parseInt(data));

                    if (dialog.getProgress() >= dialog.getMax()) {
                        dialog.setProgress(dialog.getMax());
                        currentlyLoadingFromDb = false;
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        dialog = null;
                    }
                } else if (type.equals("update")) {
                    updateLastRecipeUpdateDate();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    };

    try {
        rdAdapter = new RecipeDbAdapter(Countries.this);
        rdAdapter.open();
        recipesInDb = rdAdapter.fetchAllRecipesCount();
        rdAdapter.close();

        // Initialize database of recipes
        if (recipesInDb == 0) {
            currentlyLoadingFromDb = true;
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.setMessage("Welcome! Initializing database of recipes... This will take just a minute");
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            dialog.setMax(100);
            dialog.setProgress(0);
            dialog.show();
            updateLastRecipeUpdateDate();
            loadAT = new LoadDatabaseTask().execute("");
        }



        rdAdapter.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    try {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {}
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (dialog!=null)
    try {
          dialog.show();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {}
  }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your not restarting the application are you? if the async task is still going i assume that your app was just paused and will go through onResume instead. onResume should show it and onPause should dismiss it, if not create a taskbar notifier.

Comment: Not restarting the app, just clicking on home and returning to it. I thought onResume would resolve it but it didn't. I'd like the user not to be able to click around in the app until the db load is complete, so having the ProgressDialog on would accomplish that.

Comment: but do you dismiss the dialog when you go away from the app, if you don't an exception with the windowing system occurs. watch logcat when you go to the home screen if your dialog is still open when you navigate away. make sure that when onPause is called it dismiss's the dialog.

Comment: so I should dismiss it in the onPause, then show it again in the onResume? Will the progress get recorded by the thread through the dialog.updateProgress?

Comment: This is what I have now. Still the same issue. Wondering if there is any HTC Sense stuff that's causing a problem, since it works on the emulator but not on the HTC Evo.
'
   protected void onPause() {
  try {
     dialog.dismiss();
     super.onPause();
  }
    catch(Exception e) {}
    
   }
   
   protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (dialog!=null)
   try {
      dialog.show();
   }
     catch(Exception e) {}
   }
'

Comment: It's significantly long, so I added the most relevant parts. I'm puzzled as well. It works just fine on the emulator (2.2, 2.3, 4.0) but not on my HTC Evo. I also tried looking at logcat while running on the phone, but it worked fine when connected to Eclipse!

Comment: This is getting more and more strange. I connected the phone to the debugger, ran and installed the app from Eclipse, and the dialog reappeared as it should. I disconnected the phone from the debugger and tried again, and it still work. Now I uninstalled the app, transferred an updated APK to the phone for a fresh install, and this time it did not work. Very hard to debug, since it all works fine when connected to the debugger!

Comment: looks like the problem comes and goes. I'm still getting the same issue now even after restarting and no significant code changes. If anyone else has any other ideas, please feel free to add!

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if(dialog!=null)
    dialog.show();
}
```

and add this line in your manifest activity

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|navigation"
```

Comment: Thanks. I got excited when I saw the onResume instead of onRestart, but still not working.Once again, the strange thing is that it does exactly what it's supposed to in the emulator, but not on the HTC Evo.